# Measuring my app's network usage

Tags: android, wireshark

Naturally I want to keep the network usage of my android app as low as possible, the question is how to measure it. 
I managed to capture traffic with tcpdump and open it in wireshark, is that the way to go?
I have practically no idea on what all that stuff in wireshark means, obviously I have to read up on it, I just wanted to ask if there's a tutorial or tool ot whatever specifically for the aforementioned purpose?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html. Check the link

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/traffic-statistics-demo-android-tutorial/) you have very simple tutorial about measuring network usage.

You can also download [this application](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/check-your-network-in-real-time-with-network-traffic-monitor/) and try to decompile it and watch the code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) to statistics the system traffic .

Statistics the app traffic . if you use HttpClient ,try

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("http://xx.com/*");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
int flowBytes = entity.getContentLength() ; //Traffic statistics
```

if you use URLConnection  , try

```
URLConnection conn = imageUri.toURL().openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
conn.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
int flowBytes = conn.getContentLength() //Traffic statistics
```